# First Dirichlet eigenvalue of the harmonic oscillator on a bounded interval $(-a,a)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, sp.spectral-theory, gaussian

Let $a>0$ be a fixed number and consider the Hermite operator (or harmonic oscillator) defined by
\begin{equation}
Hf(x)=x^2f(x)-f''(x)
\end{equation}
for any smooth function $f$ compactly supported on the interval $(-a,a)$. Then, we may extend $H$ as an unbounded operator on $L^2(-a,a)$.

Extending from the Wikipedia link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue I would like to compute the first Dirichlet eigenvalue $\lambda_a$ of the above harmonic operator $H$ on the interval $(-a,a)$.

When working on whole $\mathbb{R}$, it is well-known that the first eigenvalue of $H$ is $1$. What I suspect from connection with the standard Gaussian measure is the following formula:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_a=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\int_{-a}^a e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}
\end{equation}

However, I cannot find a way to justify my guess. I tried to look for a relevant reference but all seem to deal with the Laplacian only, let alone the explicit formula for the first Dirichlet eigenvalue..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What makes you think $H$ has eigenfunctions with compact support?  Naively it looks like any functions with compact support are square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and all the square integrable eigenfunctions of $H$ are known.  They are just the usual harmonic oscillator wave functions, none of which has compact support.

Comment: I added more about the domain of $H$. Anyway, what I would like to figure out is the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $H$ on the bounded interval $(-a,a)$, not the whole real line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula for the first Dirichlet eigenvalue cannot be correct: for $a=1/\sqrt{2}$, the first eigenvalue is $5$.
Indeed, the eigenfunction
$$y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}(2x^2-1)$$
is positive on $(-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$, zero at the ends,
and satisfies
$$x^2y-y''=5y,$$
therefore $5$ is the smallest eigenvalue.
Your formula gives $2.071...$, which is not close.

For arbitrary $a$, eigenvalues and eigenfunctions can be expressed in terms of [Weber functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).